python script on node js app using child-process
I have a node js app that I am hosting on IIS and it has a python script that I am calling using the child-process library. It works fine when I am running the app on localhost but when I access the app hosted on IIS, the script fails immediately and logs the "function failed". Any idea why is this the case?
edit: only debug information I could get was an error code 1. And for some reason I couldnt find online what this actually means for this child-process library
 const pythonScript = path.join(
          __dirname,
          "../functions",
          "readDocument.py"
        );
 const pdfFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `../`, req.file.path);
 const pythonProcess = spawn(`C:\\Python312\\python`, [
          pythonScript,
          pdfFilePath,
        ]);
    
 let result = "";
    
 pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
          result += data.toString();
        });

let parsedResult = {};

pythonProcess.on("close", (code) => {
  if (code === 0) {
    parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
  } else {
    console.log("function failed");
  }
  res.json({ message: parsedResult });
});


Could you provide the exit code dispatched to the close event ? Without this code I can only assume the issue comes from the Python binary not being available at C:/Python312/python on IIS.

How about you add some error handling/debug messages and see whats happening?
I see absolutely no debug messages or even a error handling for the child process.
